# Why aren't the radio buttons rendered?

Tags: forms, 8

According to the documentation for [`Radios`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Radios.php/class/Radios/8.2.x), the following code should output a group of radio buttons.

```php
$form['settings']['active'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Poll status'),
  '#default_value' => 1,
  '#options' => array(0 => $this->t('Closed'), 1 => $this->t('Active')),
);
```

However, when I use this code, I get an error.

```php
public function radioComponent () {
  $form['posting_settings']['comment_preview'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Preview comment'),
    '#default_value' => '1',
    '#options' => array(t('Optional'), t('Required')),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

> Notice: Undefined index: #title_display in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Radios::preRenderCompositeFormElement() (line 20 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element\CompositeFormElementTrait.php).

> Notice: Undefined index: #id in Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Radios::preRenderCompositeFormElement() (line 30 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element\CompositeFormElementTrait.php).

Even when I use the following code, the radio buttons aren't rendered.

```
public function radioComponent () {
  $form['posting_settings']['comment_preview'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Preview comment'),
    '#default_value' => '1',
    '#options' => array(t('Optional'), t('Required')),
    '#id' => 'al1',
    '#title_display' =>'title',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Does anyone know why the radios don't render?

Comment: Just a side comment, `#options` should be an array with keys, `[0 => 'Opt 01', 1 => 'Opt 02']`. Can you provide more info? Maybe the issue its not in your `radios` code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you look at `/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/Radios.php`  you'll see it's not a render element, but a form element.

You can't use it without putting it in a form. If you search the code base for **extends FormBase**, you'll see many examples of forms that you can start from in building your own form, many of them quite simple.

For example:
`/core/modules/system/tests/modules/form_test/src/Form/FormTestProgrammaticForm.php`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond @oknate as i came to the end of typing up the question i did wonder whether the issue was because the code was not housed in a form component ... Thanks for confirming the situation... will give it a go before confirm the situation... thanks again

Comment: @oknate, `Radios` IS a `RenderElement` object, a `FormElement` extends `RenderElement`. A `Radios` element to work properly needs to be inside a form (for a couple of reasons), but it will be rendered even without a form (just `#options` will be not rendered, but drupal will try to render because its a RenderElement). Check its `namespace` `...\Render\Element\...` how will it not be a `RenderElement`?

Comment: Ah, right.  It's a form render element, not a regular render element.